# Navbar-collapse (Ipad menu) does not expands by it self in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird problem that I just can't fix. Have tried alot of different things, but none seem to work.

When my site is in collapse mode = Ipad menu shows, it looks weird. I have made an image so you can see how it looks.

[image]

Well, first of all it does not expands by it self, which it should do? You can see that the menu item Destination are outside.

Second, how do I move the menu content more to the left, so there can be the same white space on each side? right now it looks silly :(

In my bootstrap.css file, i have only made some color changes. My navbar code from the Site.css file you see here:

```
/*---------------------------------------------*\
  Navbar elements
\*---------------------------------------------*/

.navbar-inverse {
background-color: white;
border-width: 0px;
padding-top: 25px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
}

.navbar-header {
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 80px;
}

.navbar-header a {
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

    .navbar-header a:hover {
        color: #003665;
    }

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-header {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbarup {
    display:none;
}
}

.navbarup {
height: 40px;
}

.navbarmiddle {
border-top: thick solid #205882;
border-width: 2px;
}

.navbarunder {
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
padding-left: 80px;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}

.navbar-left, .navbar-right {
    float: none !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    display: block;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}

.navbar-nav {
    float: none !important;
    margin-top: 7.5px;
}

    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: none;
    }

        .navbar-nav > li > a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}
}

.links {
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 300px;
}
```

**Code (some of it):**

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img height="55px" src="~/images/logo.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarmiddle">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbarunder">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class='@Html.IsActive("Home", "Index")'>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
                        </li>
```

Can any tell me what elements i should try to tweak with css?

Comment: please give us a jsfiddle. we aren't super computers that can imagine outcomes of code

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/6u9zoe5e/

bootstrap.js placed in the footer?

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Found a way how to fix my second problem.. should insert a padding-left:0px in a mediaquery.. but still have problems with my first problem.

Btw, what you mean by bootstrap.js? bootstrap and my css file are already loadet.. its a MVC project.